Assert GCC that return value is in some range
Say I have some function
unsigned int my_random_value(unsigned int a);

that returns a value in the range 0, 1, ..., a - 1. I want to assert GCC that the return value will be in this range, but I don't know how to do it nicely. By wrapping this function, GCC could be noticed of this via
unsigned int my_random_value(unsigned int a);

static inline
unsigned int my_random_value_wrapper(unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int ret = my_random_value(a);

    if (ret >= a)
        __builtin_unreachable();

    return ret;
}

but that will be quite large in a header file, and will not let me use my_random_value to directly access this function. Is there a better way to do it, perhaps through attributes?

Unrelated and unsolicited advice: Please don't use __builtin_unreachable() the way you are using it in the sample code.

@UnmannedPlayer Any reason to why?

In order for the compiler to do something meaningful such as optimizations based on the assumption that the value is within a certain range, you'd have to write a wrapper macro. However, such a macro would have to contain branches, as does your if (ret >= a), which in turn likely leads to slower code. So what is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? Optimization? Range checking of the result? In case of the latter why not do it manually on the caller side?

@Lundin I am trying to silence the compiler at some parts (mainly switch statements relating to such a function) without explicitly needing to state that the condition is unreachable. Moreover, if I use this function, and then have something like new_a = my_random_value(a); and then while (new_a < a) { /* do something */ }, I want the compiler to convert it to a do-while loop. Everything to make it more readable and at the same time more optimized.

@aahlback And if you write the code just like that, what disassembly does it boil down to then?

@aahlback - The __builtin_unreachable is used when the code will never reach that point. In which case, GCC/clang >= -O1 will simply delete the whole if.. condition block. That's not what you asked for. Once that's gone, subsequently, my_random_value_wrapper will also disappear >= -O2 and all calls to the wrapper will be replaced with my_random_value.

@Lundin If I do not use __builtin_unreachable, then I do not get the wanted assembly. I really wanted something in terms of function attributes, but I couldn't see anything in the GCC documentation related to this (apart from returns_nonnull).

@UnmannedPlayer Yes, I meant to ask for a more concise way of expressing this restriction of the return values. I'm sorry if I expressed myself in an unclear way.


will not let me use my_random_value to directly access this function

Macros can help. Simply append
#define my_random_value my_random_value_wrapper



that will be quite large in a header file

If you're saying you'll need a large number of near-identical functions, you could generate them (using macros or a program).

Would it be possible to do this without an inlkne function, though? The problem is not the size of the header per se, but rather the compilation time which I try my best to reduce as well.


Seriously? How much does that add to compile time? 2. Unavoidable. The code can't be executed without being compiled.


Yes, you can do this using GCC attributes. You can annotate your function with the __attribute__((__returns_twice__)) attribute, so that it might return more than once. This way GCC will know that it should not make any assumptions about the return value.
unsigned int my_random_value(unsigned int a) __attribute__((__returns_twice__));

static inline
unsigned int my_random_value_assert(unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int ret = my_random_value(a);
    __builtin_expect(ret < a, 1); // This helps the compiler with branch prediction

    return ret;
}

By using __builtin_expect you're hinting the compiler about the likely outcome of the comparison.
Edit
__builtin_expect primarily helps with branch prediction optimization. To ensure that GCC doesn't complain about the default branch in switch statements, you can use the __builtin_unreachable() function to tell the compiler that a particular code path should never be reached.
unsigned int my_random_value(unsigned int a) __attribute__((__returns_twice__));

static inline
unsigned int my_random_value_assert(unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int ret = my_random_value(a);
    if (ret >= a) {
        __builtin_unreachable();
    }

    return ret;
}

Now you can assert that the return value from my_random_value will always be less than a, thus eliminating the possibility of the default branch being reached.

Doesn't that only help with branch prediction? For instance, I don't want GCC to complain about the default branch in switch statements.

I fixed it in the answer

The answer is identical to the code in the question except for the addition of __attribute__((__returns_twice__)) which doesn't seem helpful?

__returns_twice__ is meant for functions like setjmp and clone where a single call results in two returns.  I really don't think it is what you want here.  AFAIK it has no effect on any "assumptions" made about the return value (and here since my_random_value is opaque to the compiler, it's not going to make any assumptions anyway), but it alters register allocation in ways that will likely make the code less efficient, and produces warnings that would be meaningless here.
